# Detecting content change on a 16 GB pen drive within 8 sec

Tags: c, linux, driver, media

I have to detect whether the playable media (audio, video and image) has changed on a 16GB pen drive with 30,000 files, within 8 seconds for subsequent insertions. Other files such as pdf or plain text are not to be considered; this is for a media player software.

I tried `ls -l` and `md5` but it takes me 10-11 seconds. Has anyone ever solved this problem before or any strategy you can suggest?

The scenario when content can change is that the user may eject the pen drive, add more songs to it, and re-insert the same pen drive. If there is no content change then I can use the old database and thus save play-time.

I cannot rely on timestamps because renaming a file on a Windows system doesn't change the modification time.

Comment: Taking a step back... what process changes files? Can you get it to notify you there has been a change...?

Comment: Does the modification time stamp of the parent directory to which the song has been added get updated?

Comment: Git use sha1 & some header infomation to do this, and has cache mechnism. Maybe you can learn part of git.

Comment: Depending on the filesystem you're using you could also take a look at the NTFS journal.

Comment: Many file systems have change notification mechanisms.  Which one is in use?

Comment: @MartinJames : The file system can be anything like FAT 32 or NTFS

Answer (score 2):

Just check file sizes instead of md5 sums.  This should be much faster and less resource-intensive.

Comment: But the user may remove one song and another song of same size. This way we will miss that song, if I understood correctly

Comment: Or a file's contents can change without changing its size.  (For example, someone might fix a spelling mistake in an ID3 tag, replacing one character with another.)  It'd be better to look at the files' modification timestamps, instead of or in addition to the sizes.

Comment: +1 This is what rsync does with --size-only and I've seen that check 100,000s of files in seconds.

Comment: Consider a hybrid approach, check file size first, if different then definitely changed, if same then modification check, if different modification date then definitely changed, if same date do a md5sum just to be sure

Comment: @Adam: But I can't rely on timestamps , because renaming a file on Windows system doesn't change the modification timestamp. Can you please post your exact suggested approach as an answer, so that I can be more clear, if I didn't get it properly

Comment: @Adam: the hybrid approach is not helpful if the common case is lots of unchanged files.  In fact it will slow things down, as now there are even more checks to do (since short-circuiting only happens if a file is changed, which is unlikely).

Comment: @InsaneCoder: if one song is removed and another added, surely they will have different filenames, and be immediately detectable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assume your hashing the output of ls here in order to trigger a hash change on renames, additions, size changes or timestamps (for the systems that do play nice), since I'm guessing hashing 16GB split over 30,000 files would take much longer than 11 seconds (although most of this advice should work either way)

Your probably going to end up having to write your own code using a lowerlevel API to access the file list. ls is designed to be human readable not for speed. You don't need to query the human readable perms, username, groups, and so on and your going to be incurring a memory copy by piping it to md5.

You could try using the find command which seems faster and can specify just files. It would still be less efficient than a real program without having a pipe. This one is non-recursive (but so is ls -l), you can also specify custom formatting output if you want more than the name:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | md5sum
```

You could also try an alternative hash to MD5. MD5 is a cryptographic hash, it's designed to be secure against deliberate malicious collisions but is slower as a result.

[MurmurHash3](https://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3) is one of the fastest or the newer [xxhash](https://code.google.com/p/xxhash/). But it will depend on the hardware and size of the data (some hashes are optimized for small keys such as for a hashmap).

You could also try and thread it. Have one thread reading the list of files in from the drive continuously and another hashing them as fast as it can.

If your looking to do that with a standard shell however without writing your own code, it's going to be a pain.

Having said all that, your main bottleneck is probably the speed of the flash memory. All the tricks in the world won't help if your CPU is starved waiting for I/O. I'm not sure that it's a good 'challenge' as it will very a lot depending on drive manufacturer and USB version (unless that has been specified). But maybe doing all that might shave off a few seconds and bring you into your goal. Or just get a faster USB stick.